# OOP concept in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to JavaScript. I'm used to code in Java and PHP OOP before. Now I'm trying to use Express.js. And I confuse about the concept of OOP in javascript. 
It is **my app structure**

[image]

```
/controllers/update_profile.js

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var connection = require('../config/db.js');
module.exports.profil_update_data_post = function(req, res) {
//implementation
}
module.exports.profil_update_password_post = function(req, res) {
//implementation
}

/routes/update_profile.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//load controller
var profil = require('../controllers/update_profile');
//load auth middleware
var auth = require('../controllers/auth_middleware');
router.post('/', auth.isLoggedIn, profil.profil_update_data_post);
router.post('/update_my_password', auth.isLoggedIn, profil.profil_update_password_post);
```

What is the programming paradigm of my program above? Variable auth, profil, express are all objects. But there are no classes, constructors, relations between class like classic OOP in Java.

Comment: You can use classes in JavaScript. Just like any other OOP language.

Answer (score -1):

Have you look into [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), nowadays most of javascript framework support typescript for the large javascript project.